# Workbench throws error in following query. Why?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-workbench

I'm sorry to post such a low quality question, but I am truly at a loss. I can't create this stored procedure because workbench keeps telling me I have syntax errors... The two errors are surrounded by ***s and are on line 6.

When i try to save the stored procedure, the name automatically parses to `_SYNTAX_ERROR` in workbench, and the sql fails.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE fetchBudgetInfo(IN year YEAR, IN costCenter INT(11))
BEGIN
    BEGIN
    SELECT gls.gl, gls.name AS gl_name, IFNULL(budgets.total, 0) as totalBudgeted,
        IFNULL(ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN requests.ap = (SELECT id FROM ap WHERE ap.ap = 1 AND YEAR(ap.start_date) = year) THEN totalCost ELSE 0 END), 2), 0) AS ap1,
        IFNULL(ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN requests.ap = (SELECT id FROM ap WHERE ap.ap = 1 AND YEAR(ap.start_date) = year) THEN totalCost ELSE 0 END) / ((SELECT total FROM budgets WHERE costCenter = costCenter AND gl = gls.id AND YEAR(budgets.year) = year)***Error HERE (missing closing bracket)*** / 12) * 100, 2), 0 ***Error HERE (missing semicolon)***) AS ap1Ap,  
        IFNULL(ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN requests.ap = (SELECT id FROM ap WHERE ap.ap = 1 AND YEAR(ap.start_date) = year) THEN totalCost ELSE 0 END) / (SELECT total FROM budgets WHERE costCenter = costCenter AND gl = gls.id AND YEAR(budgets.year) = year) * 100, 2), 0) AS ap1Year,

        IFNULL(ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN requests.ap = (SELECT id FROM ap WHERE ap.ap = 2 AND YEAR(ap.start_date) = year) THEN totalCost ELSE 0 END), 2), 0) AS ap2,
        IFNULL(ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN requests.ap = (SELECT id FROM ap WHERE ap.ap = 2 AND YEAR(ap.start_date) = year) THEN totalCost ELSE 0 END) / ((SELECT total FROM budgets WHERE costCenter = costCenter AND gl = gls.id AND YEAR(budgets.year) = year) / 12) * 100, 2), 0) AS ap2Ap, 
        IFNULL(ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN requests.ap = (SELECT id FROM ap WHERE ap.ap = 2 AND YEAR(ap.start_date) = year) THEN totalCost ELSE 0 END) / (SELECT total FROM budgets WHERE costCenter = costCenter AND gl = gls.id AND YEAR(budgets.year) = year) * 100, 2), 0) AS ap2Year,

        IFNULL(ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN requests.ap = (SELECT id FROM ap WHERE ap.ap = 3 AND YEAR(ap.start_date) = year) THEN totalCost ELSE 0 END), 2), 0) AS ap3,
        IFNULL(ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN requests.ap = (SELECT id FROM ap WHERE ap.ap = 3 AND YEAR(ap.start_date) = year) THEN totalCost ELSE 0 END) / ((SELECT total FROM budgets WHERE costCenter = costCenter AND gl = gls.id AND YEAR(budgets.year) = year) / 12) * 100, 2), 0) AS ap3Ap, 
        IFNULL(ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN requests.ap = (SELECT id FROM ap WHERE ap.ap = 3 AND YEAR(ap.start_date) = year) THEN totalCost ELSE 0 END) / (SELECT total FROM budgets WHERE costCenter = costCenter AND gl = gls.id AND YEAR(budgets.year) = year) * 100, 2), 0) AS ap3Year,

        IFNULL(ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN requests.ap = (SELECT id FROM ap WHERE ap.ap = 4 AND YEAR(ap.start_date) = year) THEN totalCost ELSE 0 END), 2), 0) AS ap4,
        IFNULL(ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN requests.ap = (SELECT id FROM ap WHERE ap.ap = 4 AND YEAR(ap.start_date) = year) THEN totalCost ELSE 0 END) / ((SELECT total FROM budgets WHERE costCenter = costCenter AND gl = gls.id AND YEAR(budgets.year) = year) / 12) * 100, 2), 0) AS ap4Ap, 
        IFNULL(ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN requests.ap = (SELECT id FROM ap WHERE ap.ap = 4 AND YEAR(ap.start_date) = year) THEN totalCost ELSE 0 END) / (SELECT total FROM budgets WHERE costCenter = costCenter AND gl = gls.id AND YEAR(budgets.year) = year) * 100, 2), 0) AS ap4Year,

        IFNULL(ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN requests.ap = (SELECT id FROM ap WHERE ap.ap = 5 AND YEAR(ap.start_date) = year) THEN totalCost ELSE 0 END), 2), 0) AS ap5,
        IFNULL(ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN requests.ap = (SELECT id FROM ap WHERE ap.ap = 5 AND YEAR(ap.start_date) = year) THEN totalCost ELSE 0 END) / ((SELECT total FROM budgets WHERE costCenter = costCenter AND gl = gls.id AND YEAR(budgets.year) = year) / 12) * 100, 2), 0) AS ap5Ap, 
        IFNULL(ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN requests.ap = (SELECT id FROM ap WHERE ap.ap = 5 AND YEAR(ap.start_date) = year) THEN totalCost ELSE 0 END) / (SELECT total FROM budgets WHERE costCenter = costCenter AND gl = gls.id AND YEAR(budgets.year) = year) * 100, 2), 0) AS ap5Year,

        IFNULL(ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN requests.ap = (SELECT id FROM ap WHERE ap.ap = 6 AND YEAR(ap.start_date) = year) THEN totalCost ELSE 0 END), 2), 0) AS ap6,
        IFNULL(ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN requests.ap = (SELECT id FROM ap WHERE ap.ap = 6 AND YEAR(ap.start_date) = year) THEN totalCost ELSE 0 END) / ((SELECT total FROM budgets WHERE costCenter = costCenter AND gl = gls.id AND YEAR(budgets.year) = year) / 12) * 100, 2), 0) AS ap6Ap, 
        IFNULL(ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN requests.ap = (SELECT id FROM ap WHERE ap.ap = 6 AND YEAR(ap.start_date) = year) THEN totalCost ELSE 0 END) / (SELECT total FROM budgets WHERE costCenter = costCenter AND gl = gls.id AND YEAR(budgets.year) = year) * 100, 2), 0) AS ap6Year,

        IFNULL(ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN requests.ap = (SELECT id FROM ap WHERE ap.ap = 7 AND YEAR(ap.start_date) = year) THEN totalCost ELSE 0 END), 2), 0) AS ap7,
        IFNULL(ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN requests.ap = (SELECT id FROM ap WHERE ap.ap = 7 AND YEAR(ap.start_date) = year) THEN totalCost ELSE 0 END) / ((SELECT total FROM budgets WHERE costCenter = costCenter AND gl = gls.id AND YEAR(budgets.year) = year) / 12) * 100, 2), 0) AS ap7Ap, 
        IFNULL(ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN requests.ap = (SELECT id FROM ap WHERE ap.ap = 7 AND YEAR(ap.start_date) = year) THEN totalCost ELSE 0 END) / (SELECT total FROM budgets WHERE costCenter = costCenter AND gl = gls.id AND YEAR(budgets.year) = year) * 100, 2), 0) AS ap7Year,

        IFNULL(ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN requests.ap = (SELECT id FROM ap WHERE ap.ap = 8 AND YEAR(ap.start_date) = year) THEN totalCost ELSE 0 END), 2), 0) AS ap8,
        IFNULL(ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN requests.ap = (SELECT id FROM ap WHERE ap.ap = 8 AND YEAR(ap.start_date) = year) THEN totalCost ELSE 0 END) / ((SELECT total FROM budgets WHERE costCenter = costCenter AND gl = gls.id AND YEAR(budgets.year) = year) / 12) * 100, 2), 0) AS ap8Ap, 
        IFNULL(ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN requests.ap = (SELECT id FROM ap WHERE ap.ap = 8 AND YEAR(ap.start_date) = year) THEN totalCost ELSE 0 END) / (SELECT total FROM budgets WHERE costCenter = costCenter AND gl = gls.id AND YEAR(budgets.year) = year) * 100, 2), 0) AS ap8Year,

        IFNULL(ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN requests.ap = (SELECT id FROM ap WHERE ap.ap = 9 AND YEAR(ap.start_date) = year) THEN totalCost ELSE 0 END), 2), 0) AS ap9,
        IFNULL(ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN requests.ap = (SELECT id FROM ap WHERE ap.ap = 9 AND YEAR(ap.start_date) = year) THEN totalCost ELSE 0 END) / ((SELECT total FROM budgets WHERE costCenter = costCenter AND gl = gls.id AND YEAR(budgets.year) = year) / 12) * 100, 2), 0) AS ap9Ap, 
        IFNULL(ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN requests.ap = (SELECT id FROM ap WHERE ap.ap = 9 AND YEAR(ap.start_date) = year) THEN totalCost ELSE 0 END) / (SELECT total FROM budgets WHERE costCenter = costCenter AND gl = gls.id AND YEAR(budgets.year) = year) * 100, 2), 0) AS ap9Year,

        IFNULL(ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN requests.ap = (SELECT id FROM ap WHERE ap.ap = 10 AND YEAR(ap.start_date) = year) THEN totalCost ELSE 0 END), 2), 0) AS ap10,
        IFNULL(ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN requests.ap = (SELECT id FROM ap WHERE ap.ap = 10 AND YEAR(ap.start_date) = year) THEN totalCost ELSE 0 END) / ((SELECT total FROM budgets WHERE costCenter = costCenter AND gl = gls.id AND YEAR(budgets.year) = year) / 12) * 100, 2), 0) AS ap10Ap, 
        IFNULL(ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN requests.ap = (SELECT id FROM ap WHERE ap.ap = 10 AND YEAR(ap.start_date) = year) THEN totalCost ELSE 0 END) / (SELECT total FROM budgets WHERE costCenter = costCenter AND gl = gls.id AND YEAR(budgets.year) = year) * 100, 2), 0) AS ap10Year,

        IFNULL(ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN requests.ap = (SELECT id FROM ap WHERE ap.ap = 11 AND YEAR(ap.start_date) = year) THEN totalCost ELSE 0 END), 2), 0) AS ap11,
        IFNULL(ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN requests.ap = (SELECT id FROM ap WHERE ap.ap = 11 AND YEAR(ap.start_date) = year) THEN totalCost ELSE 0 END) / ((SELECT total FROM budgets WHERE costCenter = costCenter AND gl = gls.id AND YEAR(budgets.year) = year) / 12) * 100, 2), 0) AS ap11Ap, 
        IFNULL(ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN requests.ap = (SELECT id FROM ap WHERE ap.ap = 11 AND YEAR(ap.start_date) = year) THEN totalCost ELSE 0 END) / (SELECT total FROM budgets WHERE costCenter = costCenter AND gl = gls.id AND YEAR(budgets.year) = year) * 100, 2), 0) AS ap11Year,

        IFNULL(ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN requests.ap = (SELECT id FROM ap WHERE ap.ap = 12 AND YEAR(ap.start_date) = year) THEN totalCost ELSE 0 END), 2), 0) AS ap12,
        IFNULL(ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN requests.ap = (SELECT id FROM ap WHERE ap.ap = 12 AND YEAR(ap.start_date) = year) THEN totalCost ELSE 0 END) / ((SELECT total FROM budgets WHERE costCenter = costCenter AND gl = gls.id AND YEAR(budgets.year) = year) / 12) * 100, 2), 0) AS ap12Ap, 
        IFNULL(ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN requests.ap = (SELECT id FROM ap WHERE ap.ap = 12 AND YEAR(ap.start_date) = year) THEN totalCost ELSE 0 END) / (SELECT total FROM budgets WHERE costCenter = costCenter AND gl = gls.id AND YEAR(budgets.year) = year) * 100, 2), 0) AS ap12Year,

        IFNULL(ROUND(SUM(totalCost), 2), 0) AS totalCost,
        IFNULL(ROUND(SUM(totalCost) / (SELECT total FROM budgets WHERE budgets.costCenter = costCenter AND budgets.gl = gls.id) * 100, 2), 0) AS totalPercent

    FROM gls
        LEFT JOIN requests ON requests.glid = gls.id AND requests.costCenter = costCenter AND requests.status = 'approved' AND (SELECT YEAR(ap.start_date) FROM ap WHERE ap.id = requests.ap) = year
        LEFT JOIN budgets ON budgets.gl = gls.id AND budgets.costCenter = costCenter

    GROUP BY gls.id;
END
```

EDIT

This also fails....

```
CREATE PROCEDURE fetchBudgetInfo(IN year YEAR, IN costCenter INT(11))
BEGIN
    SELECT gls.id, gls.gl, gls.name AS gl_name, budgets.total as totalBudgeted

    GROUP BY gls.id;
END
```

Comment: can you run as a standalone sql outside of SP?

Comment: what I do when I get the mystery error(s)  (and I get them).. Is remove the first half of the select section.. and see if it compiles and runs outside of SP.  Then I keep adding half back ... until I find the line that is killing me.

Comment: If I remove the offending line, I get the same errors on the next line in the next block of 3.

Comment: I tried to copy into workbench but I do not have table(s) in question.         IFNULL(ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN requests.ap = (SELECT id FROM ap WHERE ap.ap = 1 AND YEAR(ap.start_date) = year) THEN totalCost ELSE 0 END) / ((SELECT total FROM budgets WHERE costCenter = costCenter AND gl = gls.id AND YEAR(budgets.year) = year)***Error HERE (missing closing bracket)*** / 12) * 100, 2), 0 ***Error HERE (missing semicolon)***) AS ap1Ap,  
 In your code post .. you do have this verbage ...

Comment: I should point out that this exact query works on a Windows machine, and not on a Linux machibe

Comment: missing from <tablename> in SP?

Comment: sorry I don't understand what you mean

Comment: see above edit?  Asking if your SP simple example is missing a From Clause on the SQL

Comment: Oh yeah sorry, my fault...

Comment: Try to include all column names from SELECT clause to your GROUP BY and try

Comment: Workbench 6.3.6 (released just a few days ago) fixed a similar error (MySQL Bug #77197), which version of Workbench are you using?

Comment: I'm using 6.2.3, I'll try upgrading and get back.

Comment: so i just spend the last hour trying to install it on debian... forget it. I have no idea how... I'll just have to use a windows system...

Comment: The procedure is [documented here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-installing-linux.html). First install the official MySQL APT repository (as mentioned in the docs) as then you'll gain access to the latest releases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both queries are incorrect. The first one uses a second `BEGIN` (without a closing `END`) and the second one is missing a `from` clause.

Answer (score 0):

ok.. what I do here is remove all the subselects and replace with constants - because at this point we do not care about the answer.. we care about running and returning data.  ()but keep all the parenthesis etc.. and boil it down to the basic framework. I can get this to come back in workbench.. Then I would add the subselects back one at a time to "see" if its breaking on a sub select or it still runs..

```
Select 

IFNULL(ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN 1 = (1) THEN 10 ELSE 0 END), 2), 0) AS ap2,
IFNULL(ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN 1 = (0) THEN 20 ELSE 0 END) / ((1) / 12) * 100, 2), 0) AS ap2Ap

from test.maketable
group by make
```

This may shed light on what the real culprit is.